# Java Generics argument mismatch

Tags: java, generics

I have an Interface `Worker` like below:

```
public interface Worker<T> {

    public void doAllTasks (List<? extends T> tasks);
}
```

There is an Abstract Class that uses above interface,

```
public abstract class AbstractWorker<T> implements Worker<T> {
    ...
    public abstract void doAllTasks (List<? extends T> tasks);
    ...
}
```

And there is a concrete Worker extending from this Abstract class,

```
public class ConcreteWorker<T extends Task> extends AbstractWorker<T>  {

    @Override
    public void doAllTasks(List<? extends T> tasks) {
    ....
    }
}
```

Notice the `Task` in the above class definition? That is an interface. `SpecialTask` is a concrete class that implements `Task` interface. Now once this structure is there, I wish to use this classes in my main Application like below:

```
Class Application {
    public AbstractWorker<? extends Task> myWorker;

    main() {
        ....
        List<SpecialTask> listOfTasks = new ArrayList<SpecialTask>();
        myWorker = new ConcreteWorker<SpecialTask>();
        myWorker.doAllTasks (listOfTasks); <-------------- ERROR!!!
    }
}
```

IDE shows me the following error in the above marked line:

```
The method doAllTasks(List<? extends capture#3-of extends Task>) in the type
AbstractWorker<capture#3-of extends Task> is not applicable for the 
arguments (List<SpecialTask>)
```

What I am trying to do is - in my main Application I want to first declare the Abstract version of my Worker first and later, based on some logic I want to instantiate a concrete version of that worker. I do not know before hand which particular implementation of `Task` I will need (so it could be the `SpecialTask` or `AnotherSpecialTask` etc. - assuming both of them implements `Task`)

Honestly being new to Java, I could not make any head or tail of that error message. Can someone please show me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `myWorker` is just `AbstractWorker<? extends Task>` - in other words, it doesn't know that the type argument is *really* `SpecialTask`. It could be an `AbstractWorker<SomeOtherTask>`, which wouldn't know what to do with a `List<SpecialTask>`.

If you only ever want `myWorker` to hold a worker that can deal with `SpecialTask`, you can just use:

```
public AbstractWorker<SpecialTask> myWorker;
```

That's still not depending on `ConcreteWorker`, but it *is* saying that it's definitely not just an `AbstractWorker<SomeOtherTask>` for example.

Comment: Is declaring `AbstractWorker<? extends SpecialTask>` better?

Comment: It is humanly impossible to write an answer even before I myself could finish reading my posted question once again. Now I know who is "Jon Skeet"!

Comment: Anyway, here's my follow-up question - when I invoke `myWorker` I have no way to know what type of `Task` myWorker is going to deal with... That it will deal `SpecialTask` or `SomeOtherTask` is determined later. So what do I need to do to still be able to declare `myWorker` and late initialise it?

Comment: @hashbrown: You can't, basically - imagine you've got two different methods, one of which uses `SpecialTask` and one of which uses `SomeOtherTask`. Each worker can only cope with the type of task it's designed for... so they represent a different set of capabilities. You can't have a single variable which safely lets you work with those capabilities.

Comment: @MichaelBrewer-Davis: I *think* that would work, but at that point there are enough wildcards involved that my head hurts :)